# Discord бот не видит реакции на сообщениях от пользователя

Tags: python, sqlite3, discord.py

Я пишу discord (discord.py) бота, который будет распределять роли и начислять поинты пользователям, если я оставляю реакцию (:white_check_mark:) на их сообщениях. Функция для начисления поинтов должна будет записывать их в бд (sqlite3):

```
@bot.event
async def add_points(payload):
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    reaction = discord.utils.get(message.reactions, emoji=payload.emoji.name)
    if payload.member.id == bot.user.id:
        pass
    elif payload.member.id == 63371... and str(reaction.emoji) == '✅':
        cursor.execute(f"UPDATE users SET points = points + {500} WHERE id = {payload.member.id}")
        connect.commit()
```

Когда я ставлю реакцию на сообщение, бот её не видит. Помогите плиз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете называть своими именами команды бота, помеченные декоратором `@bot.command()`.

Но это не касается **событий** бота `@bot.event`. Чтобы отлавливать сообщения, функция должна называться конкретно - `on_message(message)`, чтобы создать функцию, которая будет вызвана при запуске бота, она тоже может называться только `on_ready()` и больше никак.

Это же касается и события **добавления реакции**. Вы назвали функцию `add_points(payload):`, поэтому библиотека `discord-py` не может найти подходящее событие для функции с таким названием.

Правильно будет назвать функцию `on_raw_reaction_add(payload)`

Answer (score 0):

Библиотека точно `discord py`?
Если да, то у них есть функция [on_raw_reaction_add](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=reaction#discord.on_raw_reaction_add)